# Vue.js method change event doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to trigger a change event, where some statement is set from true to false and the other way around, whenever I check the "checkbox", but it doesn't work.

It's actually from this [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step) where I tried to experiment by adding this change event.

```
<div v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" v-if="task.completed">
  <ul>
  <li v-text="task.description"></li>
  <input type="checkbox" @change="changeComplete">
  </ul>
</div>




var app = new Vue ({
  el: '#root',
  data:  {
    tasks: [
           {description: 'clean room', completed: true, id: 1},
           {description: 'do homework', completed: true, id: 2},
           {description: 'go to sleep', completed: false, id: 3}
           ]
          },
  methods: {
    changeComplete() {
          this.task.completed = !this.task.completed;
          }
      }
  })
```

I would now expect whenever I check the box for a certain task that the value completed is changing, but the change event doesn't trigger and the completed value remains unchanged.

Comment: why you want to remove , just change the color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `task` property in `data` object here so you need to change in `tasks` array, And to do this you need to pass index to identify which task need to change.

```js
var app = new Vue ({
  el: '#root',
  data:  {
    tasks: [
           {description: 'clean room', completed: true, id: 1},
           {description: 'do homework', completed: true, id: 2},
           {description: 'go to sleep', completed: false, id: 3}
           ]
          },
  methods: {
    changeComplete(index) {
          this.tasks[index].completed = !this.tasks[index].completed;
          }
      }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
<div>
<div v-for="task,index in tasks" :key="task.id" v-if="task.completed">
  <ul>
  <li v-text="task.description"></li>
  <input type="checkbox" @change="changeComplete(index)">
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Or better you can change just class to revert or toggle task status

```js
var app = new Vue ({
  el: '#root',
  data:  {
    tasks: [
           {description: 'clean room', completed: true, id: 1},
           {description: 'do homework', completed: true, id: 2},
           {description: 'go to sleep', completed: false, id: 3}
           ]
          },
  methods: {
    changeComplete(index) {
          this.tasks[index].completed = !this.tasks[index].completed;
          }
      }
  })
```

```css
.completed{
  color: green;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
<div>
<div :class='{completed:task.completed}' v-for="task,index in tasks" :key="task.id">
  <ul>
  <li v-text="task.description"></li>
  <input type="checkbox" @change="changeComplete(index)">
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks buddy, that worked just fine. i will accept your answer. 
so i could also bind :task="task" pass it in changeComplete(task) and then my event also triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the task you want to complete inside the callback:

```
@change="changeComplete(task)"
```

and then:

```
changeComplete(task) {
    task.completed = !task.completed;
}
```

And your `v-if` shows the completed tasks, I suppose you want to show incomplete ones:

```
v-if="task.completed == false"
```

Here's a working copy:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  template: '<div> \
    <div v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" v-if="task.completed == false"> \
      <ul> \
        <li> \
          <span v-text="task.description"></span> \
          <input type="checkbox" @change="changeComplete(task)"> \
        </li> \
      </ul> \
    </div></div>',
  
  data: {
    tasks: [{
        description: 'clean room',
        completed: false,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        description: 'do homework',
        completed: false,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        description: 'go to sleep',
        completed: false,
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    changeComplete(task) {
      task.completed = !task.completed;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks buddy for your help. Your solution worked as well.